# Horizontal scroll on UIScrollView without pan gesture

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I make it so that when I use my UIScrollView the pan gesture recognizer selector is not called.

I want to be able to scroll in the scroll view without the pan gesture selector being called.

Here is my pan detected function:

```
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{

    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.draggableImage.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

    self.draggableImage.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

I do not want it to be called when I am using my UIScrollView at the bottom of the page.

Comment: So you want to add another gesture to the scroll view and disable the scroll view pan gesture sometimes but leave yours active?

Comment: he wants to "I want to be able to scroll in the scroll view without the pan gesture selector being called." <--

Comment: He would probably have to write his own scrolling code, considering the pan gesture is the reason why the scroll view scrolls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could remove the gesture recognizer from the scroll view

```
NSArray* gestureRecognizers = [scrollView gestureRecognizers];
for (UIGestureReconizer* recog in gestureRecognizers) {
    if ( [recog isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer Class]] )
        [recog removeTarget:scrollView.delegate action:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)];
}
```

I don't understand why this is needed to be done, but here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I haven't played with this, but my initial thought is that if you disable the pan recognizer, your scroll view isn't gonna scroll. Your scrollview calculates where and how to scroll based on the what the pan recognizer is telling it.

If you have an alternative setup to handle the scrolling, then by all means:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView;
[[scrollView panGestureRecognizer] setEnabled:NO];
```