# I want to avoid conflict with `Gesture` of `ScrollView`

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to avoid conflict with `Gesture` of `ScrollView` to meet a customer's complex animation requirements.

The reason I not want to conflict it is that when I simply gave `Gesture` as shown below, `onEnded` was not called.

In the first place, I feel that `onChanged` is called by accident, and I don't know if this way of writing is safe or not.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack {
        ForEach(0..<100) { i in
          Text("\(i)")
        }
      }
    }
    .gesture(
      gestureA
    )
  }

  var gestureA: some Gesture {
    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
      print("A onChanged:\(value)")
    }
    .onEnded { value in
      print("A onEnded:\(value)")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

I wish I could use `simultaneously(with:)`, but I don't know how to write with `ScrollView`.

If it's `UIScrollView`, I've found a way to remove the gesture recognizer as shown in the following with `removeTarget`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337648/1979953

Please let me know if there is any way to avoid conflicts.

**Edit:** I tried the following after seeing https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655465, but still `onEnded` was not called.

```
    ScrollView {
      VStack {
        ForEach(0..<100) { i in
          Text("\(i)")
        }
      }
    }
    .simultaneousGesture(
      gestureA
    )
```

Comment: What's the drag gesture there _for_? What are you trying to achieve with a drag gesture, as there may be other ways to achieve what you want

Comment: When the scroll view reaches the TOP, I want to close the scroll view to the bottom. However, this question is somewhat ambiguous because customer requirements can change rapidly. This is because I want to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: I believe that if `Gesture` is available, I can flexibly respond to additional customer requests.

Comment: 1. onEnded is not called because ScrollView handles the drag gesture by default.  2. onChanged is called once, but it should called multiple times. Therefore, you should make a custom scroll view.